# ASP.NET MVC Web API with Existing website asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api

In my project, I have three solutions :

- ASP.NET MVC 5 website (is completed)
- WEB API 2 MVC 5
- Model Library(shared between website & web api)

I use the framework Entity & Identity (in website project & web api project) so I have my users in my database with theirs information.
Now I'am currently developing Web Api but I don't know how the authentication can be the same than my website.

Where can I configure my web api project to authorize that ? I put the same connection string and I have installed Identity to my web api project.

Comment: who are the consumers of your API?

Comment: the consumers of my API will be phone app developped with Xamarin....

Comment: First, you should implement EntityFramework DbContext or IdentityDbContext in a separate class library and then reference that to MVC and Web API projects. After that, you should create and implement your custom IdentityConfig class in each project.